# Relation between adding base point to itself and scalar multiplications in ECC

Tags: elliptic-curves

In elliptic curve cryptography: If you add a base point P 10 times to itself, do you get  the point 10P or the point 11P? So if you want to calculate k*P with k=10, do you add 10 Ps or 9Ps to the basepoint?

Answer (score 3):

The rules are the same as in basic arithmetic. $2P = P + P$, $3P = P + P + P$, etc. So to compute $xP$ you add $P$ to itself $x-1$ times.